# Is there a non-unifying alternative to member/2 in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, unification

In prolog, the difference between `A = B` and `A == B` is that `=` tries to unify `A` with `B`, while `==` will only succeed if `A` and `B` are already unified.

`member/2` does seem to perform unification.

Example session:

```
?- A = B.
A = B.

?- A == B.
false.

?- member(A, [B]).
A = B.
```

I have been looking but I can't find a non-unifying alternative to `member/2`, but not found anything. Is there something built in or do I have to invent my own thing? As I'm rather new to Prolog I don't trust myself with writing a performant version of this.

**EDIT:**

I came up with the following, though I don't know if the cut is correct. Without it, it seems to deliver two answers for that branch of the code (true, followed by false) though. I'd also still like to know if there is a standard library function for this.

```
member_eq(_, []) :-
    false.
member_eq(X, [H|_]) :-
    X == H,
    !.
member_eq(X, [_|T]) :-
    member_eq(X, T).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may slightly modify builtin predicate `member/2` to use `==/2` instead of unification:

```
member_not_bind(X, [H|T]) :-
    member_not_bind_(T, X, H).

member_not_bind_(_, X, Y):- X==Y.
member_not_bind_([H|T], X, _) :-
    member_not_bind_(T, X, H).
```

Sample run:

```
?- L=[a,b,c(E)], member_not_bind(A, L).
false.

?- A=c(E),L=[a,b,c(E)], member_not_bind(A, L).
A = c(E),
L = [a, b, c(E)].
```

---

I leave this here as it solves a related question (checking if X may unify with any item in L without actually performing the bindings)

You can use double negation like this:

```
member_not_bind(X, L):- \+(\+(member(X, L))).
```

Sample runs:

```
?- A=c(e),L=[a,b,c(E)], member_not_bind(A, L).
A = c(e),
L = [a, b, c(E)].

?- A=d(E),L=[a,b,c(E)], member_not_bind(A, L).
false.
```

Comment: How does the double negation work? I'm still rather new to prolog and don't fully understand why that causes it to not bind. Also it does not seem to work: ?- member_not_bind(A, [B, C]). returns true.

Comment: `member_not_bind(A, [B, C])` succeeds as there is at least one unification possible (A=B or A=C), but no bindings are performed.  Maybe I misunderstood your requirement. You want the procedure to succeed only if no binding would be performed when using `member/2` ?

Comment: You may read this procedure as follows: `member(X,L)` succeeds for every item in L with unifies with X (and bindings are performed as necessary). Then `\+(member(X,L))` succeeds when there is no item in L for which X can be unified (thus no bindings are performed). Adding an extra `\+`  (that is  `\+(\+(member(X,L)))`  then succeeds when it's false that there is no item in L for which X can be unified, in other words when there is at leas an item in L that can be unified with X.

Comment: Clarification: I wanted the function to only succeed if == on the first argument with one of the members of the second argument would succeed.

Comment: @Vorpal: See my edit

Comment: I'm curious: What is the advantage to splitting the processing into three variables compared to something along the lines of my edit of the question (I realised the first line there is isn't needed since I posted that)? Seems like a rather convoluted way to implement it.

Comment: @Vorpal, You will see these code patterns a lot in prolog. The allow for better first clause indexing. In the example the first procedure already separates the head of the list with its tail, then it calls the second procedure. When entering the first clause the interpreter already knows if the second clause may be processed (if there is at least another item in the list), so if the first clause succeeds it may skip the creation of a choicepoint if it knows there cannot be another solution with the second clause.